# matplotlib - plot and include data gaps at END of time series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple time series line chart showing data gaps. It works if there are data points before and after the gap, but if the gap is at the end, it will cut away the gap, what I do not want. In other words, I want to keep showing the gap, even if it is at the end of the time series. How could I accomplish that?

In both cases, I end up with this:

[image]

So basically, I am missing the last two days which have no data points but I still would like to see to the right (two ticks more without data points).

Thanks in advance!

```
from datetime import time, date, datetime
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import nan
import pandas as pd

plot_dir = '/tmp/plot/'

## ----------------------------------------------------------------
## Test Data
## ----------------------------------------------------------------
price_history = [
      (datetime.strptime('2022-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d"), 1250)
    , (datetime.strptime('2022-01-02', "%Y-%m-%d"), 1000)
    , (datetime.strptime('2022-01-03', "%Y-%m-%d"), None)
    , (datetime.strptime('2022-01-04', "%Y-%m-%d"), None)
    , (datetime.strptime('2022-01-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 1250)
    , (datetime.strptime('2022-01-06', "%Y-%m-%d"), 1500)
    , (datetime.strptime('2022-01-07', "%Y-%m-%d"), None)
    , (datetime.strptime('2022-01-08', "%Y-%m-%d"), None)
]

price_list = []
date_list = []
for item in price_history:
    dt = item[0]
    if item[1] == None:
        avg_price = nan
    else:
        avg_price = int(item[1])
    date_list.append(dt)
    price_list.append(avg_price)

## ----------------------------------------------------------------
## Pandas DF - Same result
## ----------------------------------------------------------------
# ## create pandas dataframe
# df = pd.DataFrame(price_history, columns=["date", "price"])
# ## replace None with nan
# df = df.fillna(value=nan)
# logger.debug(df)
# date_list = list(df.iloc[:,0])
# price_list = list(df.iloc[:,1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,0.7), layout='constrained')
ax.plot(date_list, price_list, color = 'red', linewidth = 1.0, alpha = 0.75)
## pandas version
#ax.plot(df['date'], df['price'], color = 'red', linewidth = 1.0, alpha = 0.75)


## ----------------------------------------------------------------
## save chart
## ----------------------------------------------------------------

#plt.show()
file_name = 'my_plot.png'
if os.path.isfile(plot_dir + file_name):
    os.remove(plot_dir + file_name)
plt.savefig(plot_dir + file_name)
```

Comment: So much code. Can you boil it down to a minimal reproducible example? This will increase your chances that somebody will answer.

Comment: I cut it down to the necessary, basically removed all the layout stuff... hope it's easier to understand.

Comment: Ah, so your problem is not the gap in your data but that you want to include something like `ax.set_xlim(date_list[0], date_list[-1])`?

Comment: yes, i want to show all gaps, also if they are happening at the start or end of the timeline... will try out your suggestion!

Comment: Glad this problem was solved so easily. So, reducing it to a minimal example really is a useful advice - it looked way more complicated than it was in the end. Bonus: You can easily also recreate the plot margin `time_margin = (date_list[-1] - date_list[0])/10; ax.set_xlim(date_list[0] - time_margin, date_list[-1] + time_margin)`

Comment: yes, it certainly makes sense to slim things down, which is not always that easy (here luckily it was just a matter of stripping the cosmetics away) :)
What does the plot margin do?

Comment: It is aesthetically unpleasing if there is no space between the first/last data point and the axis. [Matplotlib automatically adjusts for margins](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html) but not if you provide `xlim`/`ylim` then it ignores the margin parameter. And speaking from experience - 90% of my questions were solved while I was trying to narrow the problem down to a minimal example. Everything becomes clearer also for the asker. Have fun with pandas and matplotlib.

Comment: Oh I understand, and yes I agree it looks better with a margin. Will incorporate that as well. Thanks for the good bonus tip!